# Positioning a headline above an image

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble positioning a headline above (not over) an image so that the text in the headline scales and repositions according to the image. I've tryed giving the img a relative position and the h1 element an absolute position, together with some 'top' 'left' twicks to position directly above the img. But when i change the scaling of the screen the text doesn't stay centered above the img.

Any suggestions? I woulde very much appreciate any help.

Thx,
Dan

Comment: Please post relevant codes

Comment: Text won't scale with the image by default. You can try using media queries or viewport units.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

Use header tag to produce the heading text and put the image in div tag.

```
<div>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <img src="http://www.example.com/images/myImage.png" />
</div>
```